# comparing two perforce versions

Tags: unix, diff, perforce

I have many files with different versions in perforce ( like some files version 1 to 3, some 1-6 etc ) I want to compare all files first and last versions using the single command.

say command is xyz.

xyz fileA ----> should give diff fileA#1 to fileA#3  (version 1 and 3)

xyz fileB ----> should give diff fileB#1 to fileB#6  (version 1 and 6)

Regards

keerthan

Comment: `p4 diff2 //depot/...#1 //depot/...#head`.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Bryan for getting there first but I'll put it in an answer:

```
p4 diff2 ...#1 ...#head
```

or whatever file spec you want to diff.

Answer (score 0):

you can write shell scrip

```
usage : ./diff_file.sh file
```

**step1** : catch file version

I think can use `for` to find the newest version

**step2** : use `diff` to compare file

diff [OPTION] file1 file2